# How can I check the Image is Touched using OnTouch()

Tags: android

I am trying to get the x,y co-ordinates on Touch of Image and on that I want to perform some action. So, can anyone tell me how to get the x,y co-ordinates of Image when it is touched. Thanks In Advance.

**My Code -**

```
public class MovableObject extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener{

    Bitmap myBmp;
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    int MoveX = 0;

    public MovableObject(Context context,int moveObject,Bitmap myBmp) {
        super(context);
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.myBmp = myBmp;
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.MoveX = moveObject;
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBmp, MoveX, 100, myPaint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                System.out.println("down...."+event.getX()+" "+event.getY());
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**By this I am getting the x,y co-ordinates where I click but I want to get the x,y when I click on my Image.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another way and I think its a best way to detect touch for any view by using [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html)

I just created a method that returns Rect instance including all the four co-ordinates of a view

```
   private Rect getLocationOnScreen(View mView) {
        Rect mRect = new Rect();
        int[] location = new int[2];

        mView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        mRect.left = location[0];
        mRect.top = location[1];
        mRect.right = location[0] + mView.getWidth();
        mRect.bottom = location[1] + mView.getHeight();

        return mRect;
    }
```

And then simply override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in your Activity and check for the co-ordinates of any view that you want to detect is touched or not,

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     int x = (int) event.getX();
     int y = (int) event.getY();

     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                                      getLocationOnScreen(imageview).contains(x, y)) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                          "ImageView Touched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> MoveX - It is the starting x co-ordinate of your view.
> MoveY -
> It is the starting y co-ordinate of your view.
> imgHeiht - It is the
> Height of the Image;
> imgWidth - It is the Width of the Image;
>
> event.getX()- It is the actual position of your X co-ordinate.
>
> event.getY()- It is the actual position of your Y co-ordinate.

```
if(MoveX <= event.getX() && event.getX()<= (MoveX+imgWidth) && (MoveY <= event.getY() && (event.getY() <= MoveY+imgHeight))){
    System.out.println("down...."+event.getX()+" "+event.getY());
    }
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

these are some of the methods you can call from an image view assuming you have this image in it. try experimenting and you me get what you need.

```
ImageView iv;
iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {           
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    event.getX();
    event.getX(pointerIndex)
    event.getXPrecision()
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: I am doing this but I want to get the x,y co-ordinate of the Image then touched.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
ImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
        }
     return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had done this but I want to get the x,y co-ordinates when the Image is Touched.

Comment: i get it, but as for me i don't know if there is any direct methods. but you sure can calculate the values relative to the images (top,left)(x,y) to the screens origin. sure its worth if we have a direct method.

Comment: @CapDroid requirement is about to get the position of some view. this will give only xy co-ordinate of the screen.

Comment: it will given position of that view which had you applied onTouch Method

Answer (score 0):

you cannot direct  get the image  co-ordinates,when you draw the image ,you can get the image area in the screen,then you can use @CapDroid method to get the image  co-ordinates

Comment: How can I get the image area?