# how to set drawBitmap to be not fullscreen

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, touch-event

I have a bitmap and I draw it like this :

```
bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                   R.drawable.anim_ctrl_panel);
Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(bit, 80, 440, paint);
```

The problem is that the image is set as fullscreen .On `onTouchEvent` method I implement the event for the bitmap and anywhere I select screen the event is implement. I want the image to have a certain position and only for that position to be implement the event. How can I do this?

EDIT: the problem was at onTouchEvent method. This is the solution :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {if(80 <= event.getX() && event.getX()<= (80+bit.getWidth()/2) && (440 <= event.getY() && (event.getY() <= 440+bit.getHeight()))){   
            //...
        }else if((80+bit.getWidth()/2) <= event.getX() && event.getX()<= (80+bit.getWidth()) && (440 <= event.getY() && (event.getY() <= 440+bit.getHeight()))){
            //...
            }
```

this help me : [How can I check the Image is Touched using OnTouch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938809/how-can-i-check-the-image-is-touched-using-ontouch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Image set in particular area, I think Rectangle is useful for this,

Something like this, (In my case Its work for me)

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
final Paint paint = new Paint();         
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());         
paint.setAntiAlias(true);         
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);         
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

Try it.

For more info look at [Android - Drawing (Core)](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/drawing.html)

Thanks.

Comment: I get the same thing...I thing my problem is the onTouchEvent method...there I put only this : if (event.getX() > bit.getWidth() / 2) and I should put a condition for y too, right?

Comment: Make a specific ImageView object and using rectangle and canvas fix the height and width (whatever you needed) and then implement onTouch for that perticluar view. (As per I unerstand your question). Thanks.

Comment: or make calculation, getX any getY for touch and make if condition to check whether it is in your image's rectangle's co-ordinates then do wahtever you want.

Comment: If you found this is the solution then please upvote it and accept as a correct answer. Its help you and also for other user. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(posX, posY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bit, 0f, 0f, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Really it's similar, but it should works. I also try to limit the area where you want to draw. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.RectF, android.graphics.Paint)