# pointer location issue for Android

Tags: android, cursor-position

while click Settings->Developer options->Pointer location,
I can get the XY coordination of any point on the screen.
I am wondering if it possible to do the same thing programmatically?

I used setOnHoverListener but the biggest problem is that
I can't get the XY coordination as long asthe pointer is in
navigation bar zone.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967039/onclicklistener-x-y-location-of-event) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909835/android-how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinates-within-an-image-imageview) and a lot of other similar questions on `SO`

Comment: but I have to run in Service

Comment: did you find answer?