# Get X/Y coordinates on ImageView touch

Tags: java, android, mobile

So, I need to get coordinates of my touch on ImageView.

I have already successfully tried to get coordinates in OnTouchListener event. But it is not what i really need.

The problem is that the resolution of the screen is much lower than the resolution of the picture in ImageView.

How to get actual coordinates (maybe certain pixels) of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android: How do I get the x y coordinates within an image / ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909835/android-how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinates-within-an-image-imageview)

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int[] values = new int[2]; 
            view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
            Log.d("X & Y",values[0]+" "+values[1]);
        }
    });
```

Something like this?

Comment: @Jana_Doe it seems strange but it always returns me 0/256

Comment: Could I see the code you're using? Also maybe try some of the other implementations from the link that I posted.

Comment: Thanks, found all required by your link

Answer (score 2):

There's getLocationOnScreen() and getLocationInWindow() methods for the purpose.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int[] locations = new int[2];
                view.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
                //view.getLocationInWindow(locations);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: it always returns me 0/256, any ideas?

Comment: Because this indicates absolute coordinate of your view. If you are looking for touch locations you can use motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() methods

Comment: Much thanks for explanation, i ve already used these methods. Works fine for me.