# Android: How to select part of image?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

In my application. There's section select block of apartment. In there a A and B block. So i want to choose A or B block from single image. Image is [image]

There is what way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use BitMap concept. Convert full image as bitmap the crop the bitmap based on (x,y) positions.

```
 Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);

 Bitmap cropbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, xpoint,ypoint,width, height);
 //default android method createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

other simple way use library like this from github

- [android-crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)

  [uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop)

  [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use `getLocationOnScreen()`and hardcode the values you want. If user clicks on certain part of the image it prompts one response, if they click somewhere else it prompts another response. More info here [Android: How do I get the x y coordinates within an image / ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909835/android-how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinates-within-an-image-imageview)