# How to design a keyboard(not real keyboard)

Tags: android, keyboard

Now I need to draw a keyboard on the screen(not a real keyboard),the keyboard is just like a drawing. Once I put my finger in one of its keys, I need to output it in a square on top of the screen. That's to say, I need to save pairs of x-y and keys. Once I got a (x,y), I output the key in the square on top of the screen. I wonder how to design this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How do I get the x y coordinates within an image / ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909835/android-how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinates-within-an-image-imageview)

Comment: You could use a keyboard image and follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909835/android-how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinates-within-an-image-imageview

Comment: That's to say, I do not need to draw every key, instead, I just need to import a picture of a keyboard and once I touch the picture, it will return with a (x,y). @PopHome2